# How to complete column with zero using tidyr complete?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tribble(~id, ~pos, ~val, 
          "foo", 1, 10,
          "foo", 2, 5,
          "foo", 3, 1, 
          "bar", 3, 13)
```

Each `id` will have position (`pos`) from 1 to 3.
What I want do to is to fill the id where there is incomplete `pos` and
fill `val` with 0. The desired result is this:

```
  id      pos   val
 foo       1    10
 foo       2     5
 foo       3     1
 bar       1     0
 bar       2     0
 bar       3    13
```

How can I achieve that with [tidyr complete()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html)?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
  dat  %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(pos, fill = list(val = 0))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Can be done using nesting within complete:</s>

As Darren Tsai points out in the comments, one just needs to include the pos variable - using the nesting is not necessary.

```
dat <- tribble(~id, ~pos, ~val, 
               "foo", 1, 10,
               "foo", 2, 5,
               "foo", 3, 1, 
               "bar", 3, 13)

dat %>% 
  complete(id, pos, fill = list(val = 0))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  id      pos   val
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 bar       1     0
2 bar       2     0
3 bar       3    13
4 foo       1    10
5 foo       2     5
6 foo       3     1
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `nesting()`? Your code works even without `nesting()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you group the data, `complete` is applied to each group; so what you want to do is:

```r
dat %>% complete(id, pos, fill = list(val = 0))
```

which gives you all `id`-`pos`-combinations, and fills missing `val` with zero.